# Login Control Issue

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm a junior in a software engineering and web development class and have ran into a problem. I need a log in page so that after a user clicks the log in button, they will be sent to my actual web page. However, every time I click the log in button I recieve this error:

```
Server Error in '/Case04' Application.

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster."
```

For this specific project, i am not concerned what the user enters as long as they enter information. I just need it so when the log in button is clicked i am sent to my actual web page which is pc.aspx.

Here is my Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<link href="login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%--Heading--%>
<form name="c_order" id="c_order" runat="server" 
action="pc.aspx" method="get">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="mclogog.jpg" alt="heading" id="heading" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<%--login--%>
<asp:Login ID="login" class="login" runat="server" size="10" maxlength="25" EventValidation="false"></asp:Login>
<p id="member" >Already a member?</p>

<%--fieldset for new user --%>
<fieldset>
 <legend id="bill">Shipping Information</legend>
       <label for="fname" >First Name<span>*</span></label>
       <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="27" />
       <label for="lname"> Last Name<span>*</span></label> 
       <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" size="27" />
       <label for="address1">Address #1<span>*</span></label>
       <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" size="57" />
       <label for="address2">Address #2</label>
       <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" size="57" />
       <label for="city">City<span>*</span></label></td>
       <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="40" />
       <label for="state">State<span>*</span> </label>
       <input type="text" name="state" id="state" size="3" />
       <label for="zip">ZIP<span>*</span> </label>
       <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" size="10" maxlength="10" />
       <label for="country">Country<span>*</span></label>
       <input type="text" name="country" id="country" size="40" value="United States" />
      <p id="ast">
        * = Required field, must be filled in. 
      </p>     
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Is this hosted on one server or in a web farm environment? The error you're getting is because viewstate on the page sent back from the client isn't matching what the server sent originally. Maybe because you're hitting a different server in the farm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your page is not handling its own events.  You have your < form > tag set up to post-back its values to another page.

< form ... **action="pc.aspx"** ... /> but your page is really called **login.aspx**.  So, when this form's content gets posted to pc.aspx, it can't decode the viewstate, because it didn't come from pc.aspx.cs.  It came from a different page.

Remove the action attribute from your form tag.  Like this:

```
<form name="c_order" id="c_order" runat="server" method="get">
```